# How to skip the search Special Character in Sitecore SXA Search

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I have worked on the `Sitecore SXA search` and Version is 10.2. Created respective `Solr` core and configuration for search then did the Indexing. After that browse the web page and type `%,$ (all special characters)` in the Search box and hit the search button which returns the search result.

How to ignore special character searches in the empty search box in Sitecore SXA? It should not return the search result when I'm using a special character